# Canon 1000D shutter stuck. How to fix?

Tags: canon, repair, shutter, canon-1000d

As you can see on the picture the shutter is stuck. What now? It is a pricey service job or this happens a lot and there is a know fix out there that I do not find on Google?

I already tried that strange "use BULB, make photo and open battery door meanwhile" stuff with no luck ([not that it is for DSLRs anyway](http://camerarepair.blogspot.hu/2009/05/simple-fix-for-stuck-shutter.html))

[image]

Comment: Yes. I am through all of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a mechanical issue. I had to replace the whole shutter.